# Script de contagem - SQLServer

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, script, procedure, tabela-banco-de-dados

Possuo a tabela `Telefone` , que grava os telefones que ligaram.
preciso fazer um script que mostre a 'quantidade' de telefones que ligaram. 
se um telefone ligar mais de uma vez não conta a mais. 
Preciso fazer via QuerySql do Microsoft SQL SERVER Management.

Comment: Pode postar a estrutura da tabela com exemplos de dados, antes e depois?

Answer (score 2):

Use o distinct

algo como

```
select count(distinct telefone) as chamadas_distintas
from chamadas
```

Answer (score 0):

Assim dá certo:

```
select count(*) num_chamadas_distintas from (
    select distinct numero from telefone
) chamadas_distintas
```